# Mac OS in Python, Open, Refresh Connections, Save, and Close Excel File

Tags: python, macos, save

I have hundreds of excel files that I need to open, refresh (this pulls external data using a commercial excel plugin), save the data in the file as a csv, and then close in a Mac OS.  I've seen solutions to this problem using the win32com package.  Are there any solutions to this in Mac OS?

Comment: You can use https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io. It does not depend on the operating system.

Comment: I believe this will let me read and write, but I don't know how it would let me refresh the connections inside of excel to pull in the data.  I really need the excel file opened inside the OS and then enough time to elapse to allow the excel plugin to pull in the data then save the file.